# lock aggregating/zoom from leaflet heatmap

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I would like to stop the splitting of the heatmap when zooming in.

In the example below, whenever you zoom in, the heatmap is reconstructed, re-aggregating the points into new, thinner, heat zones.

However, I want to lock the "heat zone" at a specific size, allowing the user to zoom in and out without changing the shape, size and color of the areas.

Is there a way? Maybe different libraries, `mapview` or something else?

```
library(leaflet.extras)

leaflet(quakes) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  setView( 178, -20, 5 ) %>%
  addHeatmap(
    lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, intensity = ~mag,
    blur = 40, max = 0.05, radius = 15
  )
```